# How can I store the produced session value from php in the android to continue connection to the server

Tags: android

You know when we use the `session_start()` in `php` file, it makes a `session_id` for the users  and the `session_id` stores on the browser. But my question is how can I store the `session_id` in android?

Comment: In 'android'? That's you!